# how to pass values in jsp from one page to another

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp

how to pass values in jsp from one page to another In html page which shows a box or table containing data like COLLEGE NAME, PLACE, STREAM(ARTS OR SCIENCE). data to the box or table is retrieved from database (mysql).
HOME PAGE HTML CODE and JSP CODE:

```
     <section id="pricePlans">

            <ul id="plans">
      <% while (special.next()) {%>
                <li class="plan">
                    <ul class="planContainer">
                        <li class="title"><h2>  <%=special.getString("collegename")%></h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="options">

                        <li><%= special.getString("stream")%> </li>
                        <li><%= special.getString("address")%> </li>

                <li><%= special.getString("verified")%>
                </li>
                <li><%= special.getString("description")%>  </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="button"><a href="moredetails.jsp">More Details</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <% }%>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

number boxes in jsp page is depends on data in data base. data will be like this
box1: iit bombay, bombay, engineering, more details,
box2: iit delhi, delhi, engineering, more details,
etc.  when i click on MORE DETAILS of IIT BOMBAY, i should get only IIT BOMBAY DETAILS. what should i do? i know that i need to pass value from homepage.jsp to moredetails.jsp. how to pass them?? i cannot put hidden value in between li or ul. help me

Comment: do you need to display only this details in moredetails page? or do you require to load more details from db base on id in moredetails page?

Comment: thanks for reply. i want to display more details

Answer (score 1):

Make one Servlet called `loadMoreDetails` which will take id as request parameter and load more details.

You can pass just id to Servlet like this

`<li class="button"><a href="loadMoreDetails?id=<%=special.getString("id")%>">More Details</a>`

Now load all details in Servlet based on id and then set the result object in request like this,

`request.setAttribute('moredetails',<object from db>);`

Now forward request from Servlet to `moredetails.jsp` like this,

`request.getRequestDispatcher("moredetails.jsp").forward(req,res);`

Now on moredetails.jsp use this object and display data like this,

`<% Object obj = request.getAttribute('moredetails');%>
name = <% obj.getName(); %>`

**NOTE** : Here I have used `Object` for just example. You can use your domain object or POJO.

Comment: i am not good at servlets. can you give me an example link. Or give me any other way in jsp. send the value of id to moredetails.jsp and i can use it there.